# How to set initial state of H and C arrays when using Tensorflow LSTM?

Tags: tensorflow, initialization, state, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement an Encoder-Decoder LSTM using Tensorflow. For the first encoder layer, I want to:

- set the initial state for the **H (hidden state)** as as array of all ones
- and set the initial state for the **C (cell state)** as an array of all zeros

Here is a portion of my code:

```
h = tf.zeros([batch_size, cells])
c = tf.zeros([batch_size, cells])

init_states = [h,c]

e_lstm,es_h, es_c = eSTM(
  e_embed,
  initial_state=init_states)
e_states = [es_h, es_c,]

# ...snip...

model.fit([encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data], decoder_output_data, batch_size=50, epochs=15)
```

However I keep getting an error with an *incompatible shape* on the back pass.

### Complete code

```
h = tf.zeros([batch_size, cells])
c = tf.zeros([batch_size, cells])

init_states = [h,c]

e_lstm,es_h, es_c = eSTM(
  e_embed,
  initial_state=init_states)
e_states = [es_h, es_c,]

d_inputs = Input(shape=(m_answers,))

d_embed = Embedding(
  VOCAB_SIZE,
  cells,
  mask_zero=True
  )(d_inputs)

dSTM = LSTM(
    cells,
    return_state=True,
    return_sequences=True)

d_outputs, _, _, = dSTM(
    d_embed,
    initial_state=e_states)

DDense = Dense(
    VOCAB_SIZE,
    activation='softmax')

output = DDense(d_outputs)

model = Model([e_inputs, d_inputs], output)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
    loss='categorical_crossentropy')

model.summary()

model.fit([encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data], ecoder_output_data, batch_size=50, epochs=15)
```

I am not sure of what I'm doing wrong.